# Equivalent of PHP error_log for info logs?

Tags: php, logging

I use `error_log` for my logging, but I'm realizing that there must be a more idiomatic way to log application progress.  is there an `info_log` ?  or equivalent ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to append to a specified file.

```
error_log($myMessage, 3, 'my/file/path/log.txt');
```

Note that you need to have the 3 (message type) in order to append to the given file.

You can create a function early on in your script to wrap this functionality:

```
function log_message($message) {
    error_log($message, 3, 'my/file/path/log.txt');   
}
```

Comment: yes... but what if something is not an error?  this seems like it isn't idiomatic.  In java, we have log.info("..."), log.error("error msg") , etc, as the common idiom for logging .

Comment: Yes, other languages are better than php at naming conventions, etc.  Since php doesn't actually have a logging system (for just normal messages) you have to create your own function to do it.  The function above will add the message to the file `log.txt`, not to the regular php error log.  
So if something was an error, you would use `error_log($message)` and if something was NOT an error, then you would use `log_message($message)` and read it later at log.txt.  If you want to get fancy, you can add time and file locations to the message log.

Comment: It would have been nice if php added E_USER_INFO and E_USER_DEBUG defines which could be used with trigger_error()/user_error().

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent is [syslog()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.syslog.php) with the `LOG_INFO` constant:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO, 'Message');
```

If you want to use a file (not a good idea because there is no log rotation and it can fail because of concurrency), you can do:

```
file_put_contents($filename, 'INFO Message', FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use Monolog:
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

You can add the dependency by composer:

```
composer require monolog/monolog
```

Then you can initialize a file streaming log, for an app called `your-app-name`, into the file `path/to/your.log`, as follow:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('your-app-name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));
```

Monolog is very powerful, you can implement many types of handlers, formatters, and processors. It worth having a look:
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md

And finally call it like:

```
// add records to the log
$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

In order to make it global, I recommend you to add it to your dependency injector, if you have one, or use a singleton with static calls.

Let me know if you want more details about this.